# How to Trigger DropDownList Events Inside Kendo Scheduler Resources (Popup)

Tags: c#, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-scheduler

I have below kendo scheduler code in my `.Cshtml` page

```
<div class="space-6"></div>
    <div class="row">
      <label>Procedure Code</label>
        @Html.Partial("Partials/_ProviderCodeHint")
  </div>

@(Html.Kendo().Scheduler<AppoinmentModel>()
    .Name("AppoinmentModelSchduler")
    .Views(views =>
    {
        views.DayView();
        views.WorkWeekView(workWeekView => workWeekView.Selected(true));
        views.WeekView();
        views.MonthView();
        views.AgendaView();
    })
    .Resources(resource =>
    {
        resource.Add(m => m.ProcedureCode_Id)
             .Title("Pro Code")
             .DataTextField("DisplayText")
             .DataValueField("DataField")
             .Name("ProcedureCode_Id")
             .DataSource(p => p.Read(x => x.Action("GetProcedureCodes", "OfficeAppointment").Data("_ProviderCodeHint_SupplementData")).ServerFiltering(true));
    })
    .DataSource
    (
         d => d.Model(m =>
         {
             m.Id(f => f.Id);
             m.Field(f => f.Title).DefaultValue("No title");
             m.RecurrenceId(f => f.RecurrenceId);
         })
        .Events(x => x.Error("kendoGridErrorHandle"))
        .ServerOperation(true)
        .PageSize(500)
        .Read(x => x.Action("Scheduler_Appointment_Read", "OfficeAppointment").Data("Scheduler_SupplementData"))
        .Create(x => x.Action("Scheduler_Appointment_AddUpdate", "OfficeAppointment").Data("Scheduler_SupplementData"))
        .Update(x => x.Action("Scheduler_Appointment_AddUpdate", "OfficeAppointment").Data("Scheduler_SupplementData"))
        .Destroy("Scheduler_Appointment_Delete", "OfficeAppointment")
    )
)
```

> I'm binding Drop down by calling another partial view.

**The Partial view Code**

```
<script>

    function _ProviderCodeHint_SupplementData() {
        var providerCodeCombo = $("#_ProviderCodeHint").data("kendoDropDownList");

        return {
            ProviderCodeId: providerCodeCombo.value()
        };
    }

    function providerCodeHintOnChange() {
        alert('Tested');
    }

</script>

@(
 Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
        .Name("_ProviderCodeHint")
        .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "input-xlarge" })
        .DataValueField("DataField")
        .Events(x => x.Change("providerCodeHintOnChange"))
        .DataTextField("DisplayText")
        .DataSource(p => p.Read(x => x.Action("GetProcedureCodes", "OfficeAppointment").Data("_ProviderCodeHint_SupplementData")).ServerFiltering(true))
)
```

Evert hing works good. But when i try to add a drop down list events. Its not getting fired. I have tried `Jquery` and `.Events` of kendo.

if i use `.Events` of kendo its getting triggered when the Resource is loading time itself.

Guide me to Trigger an `onchange event` inside popup after loading popup from the click of Scheduler cell onclick.

Right now `Jquery` is not working for the `Onchange` due to loading priority.

Comment: sorry just to clarify what happens when you use .events...??

Comment: Hi @Shaz no probs., Sorry for the late reply. When i use .event at `Resources`  i'm getting continues event triggering for each item in Dropdownlist creation or Load Time.

Comment: Thanks @Shaz I Utilized my thinking on events through your comment. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Myself found the Solution.,

While loading `Scheduler` there itself i have called `script function and initialized events` `.Events(eve => eve.Change("OnLoad")`

**In Partial View:**

```
.DataSource
    (
         d => d.Model(m =>
         {
             m.Id(f => f.Id);
             m.Field(f => f.Title).DefaultValue("No title");
             m.RecurrenceId(f => f.RecurrenceId);
         })
        .Events(x => x.Error("kendoGridErrorHandle"))
        .ServerOperation(true)
        .PageSize(500)
        .Read(x => x.Action("Scheduler_Appointment_Read", "Appointment").Data("Scheduler_SupplementData")).Events(eve => eve.Change("OnLoad"))
        .Create(x => x.Action("Scheduler_Appointment_AddUpdate", "Appointment").Data("Scheduler_SupplementData"))
        .Update(x => x.Action("Scheduler_Appointment_AddUpdate", "Appointment").Data("Scheduler_SupplementData"))
        .Destroy("Scheduler_Appointment_Delete", "Appointment")
    )
```

**In Script:**

```
function OnLoad() {
        $('select[data-bind="value:ProcedureCode_Id"]').change(function () {
            $('input[data-bind="value:title"]').val($('select[data-bind="value:Provider_Id"]')[0].selectedOptions[0].text + ", " + $('select[data-bind="value:ProcedureCode_Id"]')[0].selectedOptions[0].text);

        });

        $('select[data-bind="value:Provider_Id"]').change(function () {
            $('input[data-bind="value:title"]').val($('select[data-bind="value:Provider_Id"]')[0].selectedOptions[0].text + ", " + $('select[data-bind="value:ProcedureCode_Id"]')[0].selectedOptions[0].text);

        });
    }
```